# Distribution of normal force of a lever system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, elasticity, contact-mechanics

[image: 1]

So from the diagram, there is a rigid solid subjected to a downward applied point force on its rightmost end, and a fixed pivot on its leftmost end. The rigid solid A is in contact with an elastic solid B as shown. Assume the system is at rest. The problems are, how is the normal force from solid B on Solid A distributed along the red line? How can the maximum normal force be found? and what is the deformation of the elastic solid B?

I think this should relate somehow to contact mechanics (e.g. Hertzian contact stresses), but I have yet to found a satisfactory explanation as to the questions I raised.
It is also interesting to note that the distribution of normal reaction force is often overlooked in classic problems.